# Scaling issue in saving UIImage as NSData

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimage, scale

I would like to save some image as nsdata into a plist and retrieve it later.
But I got a problem.

The problem is, if the UIImage with a scale of 2.0, when I load it again later with

```
[UIImage imageWithData:]
```

the image show 2x size

What I want is to like the behaviour of

```
[UIImage imageNamed:]
```

which will load according to the screen scale.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally solve it by this code:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
if (isRetinaDisplay)  {
    image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[image CGImage] scale:2.0f orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could take into account the possibility that the screen is Retina like so:

```
CGFloat screenScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data scale:screenScale];
```

This code covers both cases (Retina / non-Retina) in one line.

Answer (score 1):

Since iOS 6 you can also use

```
+ (UIImage *)imageWithData:(NSData *)data scale:(CGFloat)scale NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0);
```

Answer (score 0):

The scale property is read-only, but what you can do is subclass UIImageView to make it writable (or make it automatic according to what device it's running on).

```
// ImageView.h
@interface ImageView : UIImageView

// ImageView.m

CGFloat scaleProperty = 1.0;
@implementation ImageView
- (void)setScale:(CGFloat)scale
{
    scaleProperty = scale;
}

- (CGFloat)scale
{
    return scaleProperty;
}
@end
```